# substitute at beginning of line

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, tcl

I want to search a pattern and insert a character at the beginning of a line using `regsub` in TcL. I have to use TcL only

### Input file

```
mna1 x a1 vss vbn nch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_n1 l=ln1
mna2 x a2 vss vbn nch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_n2 l=ln2
mpa2 vdd a2 net10 vbp pch_mac nfin=nfin_p2 l=lp2
mpa1 net10 a1 x vbp pch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_p1 l=lp1
```

### Desired output

```
mna1 x a1 vss vbn nch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_n1 l=ln1
mna2 x a2 vss vbn nch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_n2 l=ln2
*mpa2 vdd a2 net10 vbp pch_mac nfin=nfin_p2 l=lp2
mpa1 net10 a1 x vbp pch_svt_mac nfin=nfin_p1 l=lp1
```

### command used

```
regsub -nocase {pch_mac} $file_pointer {\*$1} file_pointer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add text at the *beginning* of the line, you have to match all the characters from the beginning of the line:

```
regsub {^.*pch_mac} $file_pointer {*&} file_pointer
```

Here, `&` in the replacement part is substituted with all the text that matched the expression, i.e. all the chars from the beginning of the line to "pch_mac". See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm

Perl uses the `$1` notation, Tcl uses `\1` **if** you use capturing parentheses:

```
regsub {^(.*pch_mac)} $file_pointer {*\1} file_pointer
```

Another way to write this is

```
if {[string first pch_mac $file_pointer] != -1} {
    set file_pointer "*$file_pointer"
}
```